# How to create random size table in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python, and I am trying to write a function called get_table. It's purpose is to get the data for the table from the random number library function. It should create the table, making sure that is it square and return it. I have no idea where to start, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: First. Have you tried to learn the basic concepts of Python?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your explanation:

```
import random

def get_table():
    random_size = random.randint(1,10)
    return [[0 for _ in range(random_size)] for _ in range(random_size)]

for item in get_table():
    print(item)
```

Now, if you want to fill the table with `random` numbers, change `0` with `random.random()`.

P.S. This table goes up to `10x10` but you can change that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy`. For example, a 3x3 matrix:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.random((3,3))
array([[ 0.14386109,  0.62347273,  0.23452904],
       [ 0.01243438,  0.59093442,  0.13123467],
       [ 0.11244109,  0.54378559,  0.79454328]])
```

This allow you to create the array. This might be enough for your need. If not, you just need to build this into a function. For that, take a look at the [documentation](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Functions).